# 08001 appear while connecting with mssql server

Tags: php, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect php with mssql using

```
$serverName = "BLFC\SQLEXPRESS:600"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (1433 by default)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"test", "PWD"=>"abc@123$!@#");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if($conn) {
    echo "Successfuly connected.<br />";
} else {
    echo "Connection error.<br /><pre>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

While running this on browser the sqlsrv_errors throws connection error.

```
Connection error.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => HYT00
            [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 87
            [code] => 87
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 87
            [code] => 87
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )

)
```

I confirm my port number and serverName\instanceName are defined correctly.

Please provide me some insights if there is some syntax errors that needs a correction

Comment: Quite often SQL Server connect strings expect port with comma. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i had tried that as well but still getting same error